# Putting two lists into a third list

Tags: python, list

How to join two lists into a third list?

e.g: if there are two lists `[1,2,3]`, `[4,5,6]`. I want my output to be 
`[[1,2,3][4,5,6]]`.

Can someone suggest me how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Simply create a new list containing the others:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = [4,5,6]
>>> [a, b]
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a=[1,2,3]
b=[1,2,3]
c=[]
c.append(a)
c.append(b)
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should also contain an explanation.

Comment: @BDL Well, it's a good practice to answer a question with an explanation. But the code is too easy and obvious to be explained.